# Inequality for some $L^p$ function

Tags: lp-spaces, calculus-of-variations

I have a question regarding a proof of a lemma (I.1) in P.L. Lions "concentration-compactness principle" (locally compact case, 2nd part (See p.10 [here](http://archive.numdam.org/article/AIHPC_1984__1_4_223_0.pdf)). Here it is:

> Let $1 < p \leq \infty$, $1 \leq q < \infty$ with $q \neq \frac{Np}{N-p}$ if $p<N$. Assume $u_n$ is bounded in $L^q$ and $\nabla u_n$ is bounded in $L^p$ and we have 
>   $$\sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}^n} \ \int_{y+B_R} |u_n|^q \rightarrow 0$$
>   for some $R > 0$. Then $u_n \rightarrow 0$ in $L^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in [q, \frac{Np}{N-p}]$.

Now to the proof: We first assume that $u_n$ is also bounded in $L^{\infty}$. He picks $q_1 > q$, $\infty > (q_1 - 1)p' > q$.

He remarks that by Hölder:

\begin{alignat*}{1}
\underset{y \in \mathbb{R}^n}{sup}\int_{y + B_R}|u_n|^{q_1-1}||\nabla u_n| \rightarrow 0
\end{alignat*}
So far so good. 
Then he claims that by Sobolev embeddings, if $\gamma \in ]1, \frac{N}{N-1}[$ ($N$ being the dimension) there exists a constant $c_0$ independent of y such that:

\begin{alignat*}{1}
\int_{y + B_R}|u_n|^{q_1\gamma} \leq (\int_{y + B_\rho}|u_n|^{q_1} + |u_n|^{q_1-1}|\nabla u_n|dx)^{\gamma}\\
\leq \epsilon_n^{\gamma - 1}\int_{y + B_\rho}|u_n|^{q_1} + |u_n|^{q_1-1}|\nabla u_n|
\end{alignat*} 
I am totally lost by those 2 last inequalities. It do not understand how we can introduce the $\nabla u_n$ term. If I had to guess the term $\epsilon_n$ is just $(\int_{y + B_\rho}|u_n|^{q_1} + |u_n|^{q_1-1}|\nabla u_n|dx)^{\gamma-1}$, I do not see why this quantity can be made small, a priori we only know it is bounded. Also I do not see why we have to change the radius of the ball from $R$ to $\rho$. Thanks a lot for any ideas on how to tackle this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Omega = y + B_R$. Since $u_n \in L^{\infty}$ and the measure of $y + B_R$ is finite, $|u_n|^{q_1} \in L^1$. Moreover, $|\nabla |u_n|^{q_1}| = q_1|u_n|^{q_1-1}|\nabla u_n|$ is integrable as well. Therefore, $u_n \in W_1^1(\Omega)$. Thus, by the Sobolev embedding theorem, 
$$\left(\int_{\Omega}|u_n|^{q_1\gamma}\right)^{1/\gamma} = ||(|u_n|^{q_1})||_{L^\gamma} \le c_0||(|u_n|^{q_1})||_{W_1^1} = c_0\int_{\Omega}\left(|u_n|^{q_1} + q_1|u_n|^{q_1-1}|\nabla u_n|\right).$$
In other words,
$$\int_{\Omega}|u_n|^{q_1\gamma} \le C\left(\int_{\Omega}|u_n|^{q_1} + |u_n|^{q_1-1}|\nabla u_n|\right)^{\gamma},$$
which, I believe, is how the first inequality should look like. Next, I think, we are going to observe that
$$\epsilon_n = \sup\limits_{y \in \mathbb{R}^n}\int_{y+B_R}|u_n|^{q_1} + |u_n|^{q_1-1}|\nabla u_n| \to 0$$
as $n \to \infty$. Note that $\epsilon_n$ does not depend on $y$. It follows that
$$\int_{\Omega}|u_n|^{q_1\gamma} \le C\epsilon_n^{\gamma-1}\int_{\Omega}|u_n|^{q_1} + |u_n|^{q_1-1}|\nabla u_n|$$

I am relatively sure the next step would be something like covering $\mathbb{R}^n$ with balls of radius $R$ and, choosing $\gamma$ approprietly get the estimate
$$||u_n||_{L^\alpha} \le C_0\epsilon^{\gamma-1} \to 0.$$

Comment: Yes, you are totally right with your guess at the end, very nice! Thank you!

Comment: It is clear to me why $\gamma > 1$, the other endpoint $\gamma < \frac{N}{N-1}$ less so. The argument with the epsilon still goes through, moreover we only need Sobolev not Rellich-Kondrachov to control the norm, so this should be fine. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @mvenzin, to your first question: we use the embedding theorem for the function in $W_1^1$, so $\gamma \in (1, 1^* = \frac{N}{N-1})$ where $p^*$ is Sobolev conjugate. To your second question: here I need only the continuity of the embedding so it doesn't really matter, but, I suppose, using R-K would be more formally correct. I want to say that I think the key assumption is that $u_n \in L^{\infty}$. It makes our life infinitely (hehe) easier. I used it explicitly when i said $|u_n|^{q_1}$ is $L^1$ and implicitly when I said $\epsilon_n \to 0$.

Comment: Nice pun :). I am not sure to understand your answer concerning the need for $\gamma \in (1, 1*)$, then again, I think I have formulated my question badly. What I mean is that since we use the Sobolev embedding (we do not need R-K), we have $\int_{B_R}|u|^{q_1 * \frac{N}{N-1}} \leq (|| |u_n|^{q_1} ||_{W^{1,1}(B_R})^{\frac{N-1}{N}}$. I do not see where the argument then breaks down. Thank you for time!